# Java deserialization gone wrong

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, deserialization

## Edit:

I found the problem, it was related to the way I extracted the `Date` from my JavaFX `ComboBox`es, and to the fact that Java's `HashMap` stores keys and values *by reference* and not *by value*.
Thanks for everyone who help me during the process ^^

---

## Overview

I'm writing a simple JavaFX exercise to represent a notebook.
Each note has a date, and is represented by a String, so the notebook is actually a `HashMap<Date, String>`, where the `Date` is my own written hashable and serializable class. The notebook should be written to a file and loaded from a file as needed (I'm using `FileChooser` for this methodology).

## My problem

The problem is that I can write a notebook to a file, and immediately read a notebook from the same file, but the **deserialized HashMap is incomplete**, and also some notes are appear in the **wrong date**.

## My steps to try and solve the problem

1. I know that `HashMap` and `String` implement Serializable, so all left is to make `Date` serializable as well; Below is the class' code (without c'tor and getters / setters):

```java
public class Date implements Serializable {
//    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Date date))
            return false;
        return day == date.day && month == date.month && year == date.year;
    }
    
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(day, month, year);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", day, month, year);
    }
}
```

2. After making sure my `HashMap<Date, String>` is serializable, it's time to read and write from/to it:

```
public static void loadNotebook(File file) {
        currentFile = file;

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
            Object deserializedObject = ois.readObject();
            if (deserializedObject instanceof HashMap) {
                currentNotebook = safelyCastObjectToHashMap(deserializedObject);
                System.out.println("Total notes loaded: " + currentNotebook.size());
                return;
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static boolean saveNotebook() {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(currentFile);
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
            oos.writeObject(currentNotebook);
            System.out.println("Total notes saved: " + currentNotebook.size());
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

> It's worth mentioning that `currentFile` is a static `File` instance, and `currentNotebook` is a static `HashMap<Date, String>`. I've decided to use `static` methodology as for there's only *one* notebook read and written to at any given time during the run of the application.

3. As can be seen in the code above, I've also logged some *debugging information* to better understand my problem; Every time I load/save a file, I also write how many notes where written from/to the file. In order to debug this issue, I've added three notes to the notebook, saved it to a file (called `saveNotebook`), and then immediately read from the same file (used `FileChooser` to choose the same file and called `loadNotebook`. The results where surprising:

```
Total notes saved: 3
Total notes loaded: 1
```

> It's worth mentioning that adding each note is just calling `currentNotebook.put(key, value)` with the user provided date and string. The *"Total notes saved"* debugging log holds the correct amount of notes in the notebook, so I don't believe that's what causing the problem.

---

## Summary

So... any ideas what's causing the problem? Is there something obvious I missed the whole time?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, both with helping me solve the problem and with helping me describe the problem better if I can :)

I tried the whole steps above, I expected the `HashMap` to hold the same information after serialized and deserialized, but it had actually less information, and some of it was wrong (values that belonged to the wrong keys).

Comment: What does `safelyCastObjectToHashMap` do? And isn't it an option to replace your custom `Date` class with `LocalDate`?

Comment: [mcve] please .. btw: this is unrelated to javafx

Comment: @RobSpoor it basically just cast an `Object` to a `HashMap<Date, String>` using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"), because IntelliJ yelled at me that my code isn't clean.


And @kleopatra thank you for helping me describe my problem in a better way ^^

Comment: @Yoni in order for people to help you to find the issue, a [mre] is almost necessary here, since otherwise we cannot tell what goes wrong and where, since we don't have the full picture. So try to extract only the needed code for the (de-)serialization and your data classes into a seperate runnable project and provide it here.

Comment: @maloomeister what's missing?
I've described the HashMap and File being static, handled using simple `put` and JavaFX's `FileChooser`, and I provided the serialization and deserialization methods... the rest is unimportant JavaFX code... or is it? Please tell me if you need anything specific that I didn't provide

Comment: @Yoni I'm currently not able to simply copy your provided code and simply run it myself. Please take a quick minute to read the information about what a [mre] is and ideally provide one afterwards.

Comment: @maloomeister I've read it (thank you both btw for providing this post), I still don't understand what specific information is missing. Will it help if I upload it to GitHub so anyone can pull it and reproduce the problem on their machine?

Comment: @Yoni there’s a lot missing: field definitions in Date, the class that surrounds loadNotebook and saveNotebook, something that creates the HashMap and calls them. If the problem is with serialization of your Date class, you should be able to reproduce the problem by serializing and deserializing just a Date without needing a HashMap.

Comment: @TimMoore alright thank you, since this is much code I'll later on upload it to GitHub and post the link in here.

Comment: @Yoni sorry, no that’s not the right way to use this site. Please read what others are asking for and put the _minimum_ code that _reproduces the problem_ into the question text. This might require making a new test project to strip the code down to the minimum. Yes, that requires some work, but right now you’re essentially asking other people to do that work for you. Often, the process of doing this will help you work out what the problem is on your own.

Comment: @TimMoore I'm sorry, but I don't understand :(
I was being told 3 times to read the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you're request contradicts this post because in order to reproduce my issue, you need my entire project - including JavaFX's logic.

Now, after this being said, I can say that I've just found the error, and it was indeed related to the way I extracted the `Date` from my `ComboBox`es. But the main topic right now is not the problem, rather than what I've learned from it - because I'm not sure was have I learned...

Comment: To be more precise, was I supposed to add the JavaFX code as well?
Or, a more important question, was I supposed to ask you "is my code right" rather than "what's the problem"?

I want to understand better how to describe my issues in order to be a better StackOverflow user, and that might just be the point - I was actually asking "hey I'm new to Java, is there some serialization step I missed?", and if the answer was "no" than I'd know to look somewhere else (in the JavaFX code).

So, what do you think about that? Should have I asked "is this code right"?

Comment: you suspect that the problem is de/serialization: so you write a [mcve] doing nothing but de/serialize (with a in-memory InputStream  f.i.). Exhibiting the problem? debug and fix - if you can't, use that example in a question. Not exhibiting the problem? your assumption was wrong. Look elsewhere: suspect the combo? write a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (no de/serialization, just your plain data objects) .. and so on :) The idea is divide-and-conquer, reduce complexity, separate concerns to get to the real reason and enable a solution, by you or others

Comment: To your answer "was I supposed to add the JavaFX code as well?": *we don't know*. That's why **you** have to try to strip down your problem to the smallest possible thing that can demonstrate what's wrong. If removing the JavaFX code makes the problem go away, then you might have to keep at least some of it. If you remove that code and the problem persists (i.e. you can still demonstrate it some other way) then you *don't* need the JavaFX code. That process is a fundamental skill for honing in on what the exact problem is that you'll need over and over again, not just for asking SO questions.

Comment: Alrighty then, thank you all for helping me with this issue and with describing me problem, I'll try to do better next time :)